# Making a loop to write new lines to a txt file using python

Tags: python, loops, text, text-files

I'm trying to get the script to read a text file of Congress members in which each line is formatted like this:

Darrell Issa (R-Calif)

I want it to print a line to a different file that's formatted like this (notice the added comma):

Darrell Issa,(R-Calif)

For some reason the script below works but it only does it for the first line. How do I get it to execute the loop for each line?

```
basicfile = open('membersofcongress.txt', 'r')

for line in basicfile:
   partyst = line.find('(')
   partyend = line.find(')')
   party = line[partyst:partyend+1]
   name = line[+0:partyst-1]
   outfile = open('memberswcomma.txt','w')
   outfile.write(name)
   outfile.write(",")
   outfile.write(party)
   outfile.close()

basicfile.close()
print "All Done"
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files),

> 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be
>   erased)

When you open your output file with `w`, loop keeps creating a new txt file for each line. Using `a` would be better.

```
basicfile = open('membersofcongress.txt', 'r')

for line in basicfile:
   partyst = line.find('(')
   partyend = line.find(')')
   party = line[partyst:partyend+1]
   name = line[+0:partyst-1]
   outfile = open('memberswcomma.txt','a')
   outp = name + "," + party + "\n"
   outfile.write(outp)
   outfile.close()

basicfile.close()
```

**EDIT:**
Much better solution would be,
You open your output file at the begining of the loop instead of inside of it.

```
basicfile = open('membersofcongress.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('memberswcomma.txt','w')

for line in basicfile:
   partyst = line.find('(')
   partyend = line.find(')')
   party = line[partyst:partyend+1]
   name = line[+0:partyst-1]
   outp = name + "," + party + "\n"
   outfile.write(outp)

outfile.close()
basicfile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a dumb mistake. But even with that change it's not working.

Comment: Tried this and it once again only did it for the first line!

Comment: does the source file have proper line breaks, or is it all just one line? How about adding a telltale print statement in the loop, so you can see how many times it iterates.

Answer (score 0):

ok a few things to fix this, use **'a'** mode to open your outfile and open it just **before** the loop, close the outfile **after** the loop and **not inside** it.
something like this should work (tested it)

```
basicfile = open('membersofcongress.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('memberswcomma.txt','a')
for line in basicfile:
   partyst = line.find('(')
   partyend = line.find(')')
   party = line[partyst:partyend+1]
   name = line[0:partyst-1]
   outfile.write(name)
   outfile.write(",")
   outfile.write(party)

outfile.close()
basicfile.close()
print "All Done"
```

Comment: It's still only doing it for the first line!

Comment: that's weird, i've already created a file called membersofcongress.txt and it did output a file with all instances separated by commas, can you upload your original file so i can give it a try on my own computer?